# How to get same Portuguese keyboard as Ubuntu in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard-layout

I have installed Xubuntu 13.04 but am finding that the Portuguese keyboard layout is not the same as the Portuguese layout I had in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I am using the UK Microsoft Curve 2000. When I press they keyboard's 'e' key a '.' appears instead. The workaround has been to use the 'Portuguese (Macintosh, Sun dead keys)' Portuguese layout which is close but I have to stretch my fingers to the ']' key instead of the '[' key to get the accents, and I don't want to have to retrain my muscle memory for something that is likely to change.

Would remapping keys be the most viable solution or is there just something I need to install or download?

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot with current layout and the desired one if possible?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`?

Comment: My keyboard is properly configured for English (it is an English keyboard). The problem is that the Portuguese layout is different to the one I have in Ubuntu and I don't know how I can get that in Xubuntu ... how can I "see" the keyboard layout in xubuntu?

Comment: I guess what I want most is just to use the same layout program that is in Ubuntu. I want that exact same program with that exact same mapping and behaviour ... I think though that I might just have to create the mapping myself ... also I'd like to know where I can find a keyboard preview program

Comment: yes, I missed that XFCE doesn't have the layout preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `$ setxkbmap -query` in both Ubuntu and Xubuntu sessions and compare the results.

If they differ AFAIU you'll have to edit `/etc/default/keyboard`

Comment: Sweet ... I mean I've installed over Ubuntu but I can easily run it inside a VM to see what differs.